# What does Spark's API newHadoopRDD really do?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, mapreduce

I know internally it uses MapReduce to get inputs from Hadoop, but who can explain this with more details?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are thinking that is right.`HadoopRDD` RDD that provides core functionality for reading data stored in Hadoop (e.g., files in HDFS,
 * sources in HBase, or S3).
it uses `HadoopPartition`.
When an HadoopRDD is computed you can see the logs `Input split:`

example: `INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/Users/jacek/dev/oss/spark/README.md:0+1784`

properties are set upon partition execution:

1. task id of this task’s attempt `mapred.tip.id`
2. task attempt’s id `mapred.task.id`
3. `mapred.task.is.map` `true`
4. `mapred.task.partition` split id
5. `mapred.job.id`

This  `HadoopRDD` cant do nothing when `checkpoint()` called.

you can see the comment section in [HadoopRDD.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.1.0/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/HadoopRDD.scala) each and every properties are pretty explanatory.

Comment: OK, some nice info for this API, thanks. When i reading the source code you provided, i found another question: where the intermediate result been saved? the intermediate result is that, when it does the process of making a hadoop partition, it first runs a mapreduce and then call some function to generate the partition, so where the result of mapreduce (intermediate result) been stored? in memory? in disk?
thanks.

Comment: The intermediate shuffle output gets written to disk, but it often 
hits the OS-buffer cache since it's not explicitly fsync'ed, so in 
many cases it stays entirely in memory. The behavior of the shuffle is 
agnostic to whether the base RDD is in cache or in disk. HadoopRDD also uses basic RDD principle. check the API and below you can find it where it is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

New Hadoop RDD provide core functionality for reading data stored in Hadoop (e.g., files in HDFS, sources in HBase, or S3), using the new MapReduce API (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce).

It also provide various other methods for finding out the configurations details about the partitions, inputsplits etc.

You can visit the documentation for more detailed overview 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/NewHadoopRDD.html

Hope this will solve your query